# Mac OS 10.10.5 error "starting cocoa loop" and doesn't connect

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I'm using quicksynergy in ubuntu 12.04 for server and synergy(1.4.17) in MAC 10.10.5 for client. I put the screen name which comes in synergy in mac(hostname) to the left box of the quicksynergy in the ubuntu and clicked execute. I put the hostname.local of ubuntu in server ip box of the synergy of the mac. when i started the synergy of mac, it shows following in the log but when i move the mouse to the ubuntu to the left it is unable to move to mac.

logs in synergy:

```html
NOTE: starting client
NOTE: config file: /var/folders/m6/drvmhyc920vfq4gb7z4dnc4whsq3fk/T/Synergy.aQ1545
NOTE: log level: INFO
INFO: Synergy 1.4.17 Client on Darwin 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
NOTE: started client
2015-09-28 17:11:02.597 synergyc[1997:26523] starting cocoa loop
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I recognise this problem when i try to connect to my windows computer from my mac. What does the trick for me is to set the current server computer with synergy to client and put the other pc to server. then try to connect with eachother to click on apply. Most of the time this wil work. When this works, change the settings correct again on the machines and try to connect. This works for my pc most of the times.